NNModel (ONNX) Assertion Error in Barracuda
I am trying to use a ONNX model for inference in Unity using Barracuda, following this repo. When I try to call model inference, I get the following assertion error.
AssertionException: Assertion failure. Value was False
Expected: True
UnityEngine.Assertions.Assert.Fail (System.String message, System.String userMessage) (at <cb81df0c49c643b1a04d9fc6ccca2433>:0)
UnityEngine.Assertions.Assert.IsTrue (System.Boolean condition, System.String message) (at <cb81df0c49c643b1a04d9fc6ccca2433>:0)
UnityEngine.Assertions.Assert.IsTrue (System.Boolean condition) (at <cb81df0c49c643b1a04d9fc6ccca2433>:0)
Unity.Barracuda.PrecompiledComputeOps.PRelu (Unity.Barracuda.Tensor X, Unity.Barracuda.Tensor S) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.barracuda@3.0.0/Barracuda/Runtime/Core/Backends/BarracudaPrecompiledCompute.cs:1501)
Unity.Barracuda.StatsOps.Unity.Barracuda.IOps.PRelu (Unity.Barracuda.Tensor X, Unity.Barracuda.Tensor S) (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.barracuda@3.0.0/Barracuda/Runtime/Core/Backends/StatsOps.cs:543)
Unity.Barracuda.GenericWorker+<StartManualSchedule>d__36.MoveNext () (at ./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.barracuda@3.0.0/Barracuda/Runtime/Core/Backends/GenericWorker.cs:1143)
...

The stack trace references this assertion statement Assert.IsTrue((X.flatWidth == S.flatWidth) || (S.flatWidth == 1)); in Barracuda's PRelu method. How can I deal with this error?
I have applied the following preprocessing on an image I uploaded to Unity and accessed as a Texture2D object prior to calling inference:
// Goal: Resize texture to proportionally scale image to have largest dimension be 192,
//       targetX and targetY input corresponds to width & height to achieve this
private Texture2D preprocess(Texture2D texture2D, int targetX, int targetY)
{
    RenderTexture rt = new RenderTexture(targetX, targetY, 24, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32);
    RenderTexture.active = rt;

    Graphics.Blit(texture2D, rt);
    Texture2D resizedTex = new Texture2D(targetX, targetY, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    resizedTex.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, targetX, targetY), 0, 0);
    resizedTex.Apply();

    // Pad image to make square
    int offsetX = (192 - resizedTex.width) / 2;
    int offsetY = (192 - resizedTex.height) / 2;
    Texture2D paddedTex = new Texture2D(maxSize, maxSize, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    Color[] texPixels = resizedTex.GetPixels();
    paddedTex.SetPixels(offsetX, offsetY, resizedTex.width, resizedTex.height, texPixels);
    paddedTex.Apply();

    RenderTexture.active = null;
    return paddedTex;
}

I am using this Texture2D object to convert to a Tensor using Tensor inputTensor = new Tensor(texture, channels: 3);. I've verified that the input dimensions for the model I am using should be 192 by 192 with 3 channels. I've noticed previous posts referencing Barracuda documentation that states "The native ONNX data layout is channels-first. Barracuda automatically converts ONNX models to channel-last layout." but I am not sure how I would apply this information to change my input tensor. My Barracuda version is 3.0.0.

Update:

After looking through Unity Barracuda documentation I realized that it is being replaced with a package called Sentis. Refactoring the code to use Sentis instead of Barracuda was one of the steps I took to make model inference run correctly.

Using the Sentis TextureConverter.ToTensor(texture); resulted in an input shape that was (1,3,192,192) which is channels-first data layout. This was not my initial problem but it ended up not matching the input shape for my model. I was able to re-export the model I was using the tf2onnx library, specifying my desired channels-first inputs using the flag --inputs-as-nchw.  Here is the package reference.


